# How to get user input in the J programming language

Tags: input, io, user-input, j

I'm very new to the J programming language, so I got interested in array programming languages and decided to give it a go.
Unfortunately, It's a very niche language, meaning that there aren't many learning resources available.
For that reason, I haven't figured out how to get user input in J, I'm making a simple program where the program asks the user for a name and greets them.

I tried asking ChatGPT for the solution, However, It didn't work.
I'll still show the code it told me: `insertVariableNameHere =: 1!:1]0`
I also tried searching for it, but it gave me results on java, jquery, javascript, and other unrelated languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ChatGPT is close, but in terse languages like J, close is not good enough. It does use `1!:1` which is the 'read from files' foreign conjunction, but it needs to have the argument 1 and not 0.

```
   read=: 1!:1  NB. read becomes a verb to read from file
   variable=: read 1 NB. 1 designates keyboard as the source to be read
1 2 3 4    NB. indented waiting for input
   variable  NB. Now contains what you entered.
1 2 3 4
```

Nothing that you are asking here is obvious or dumb. There is a lot of information about J in the J wiki and a really good place to start is here: https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/For_New_Users
or for more learning materials:
https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Books

If you move off of jconsole onto either JQt or JHS environments you also get the benefit of the J labs which are interactive tutorials. Enjoy your journey with J.

Comment: This does work, partially, Whenever executing a file I edited in a code editor/IDE, It doesn't work, however, when I type each line in the JConsole, it works. I execute it by loading the file by the `load` verb to load my file. like so: `load 'filename.ijs`

Comment: You might take a look at this. https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Guides/J_Shell_Script My solution used the argument of `1` which is for keyboard input. The different options for the `1!:1 `and `1!:2` can be seen on this page. https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/Foreigns#m1

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
greeting=:3 : 0
input=:1!:1[1
echo 'Hello ',input
)
```

Sample run:

```
greeting ''
Jason
```

Output:

```
Hello Jason
```